# From PendingIntent to Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I try to display a notification each day at a given time, so I use the AlarmManager, which activates my PendingIntent. Now I'm trying to make this PendingIntent to show a notification. Any ideas on how I should make this work?

My code:

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    check_products(7, 0);
    check_products(16, 0);
}

public void check_products(int hour, int minute){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}
```

Comment: Could you ellaborate on why your current code doesn't work?

Comment: @aochagavia I simply don't know how/where to define my notification...

Answer (score 0):

you have to make a broadcast receiver for your task, as the given time meets requirement then generate a notification using PendingIntent...

Comment: I think I have something like that, but I don't know how to define a notification via a PendingIntent...

Comment: can you send me your email so that i can send you a code to generate notification in Pending Intent..

Comment: Could you maybe post it here, so it will be helpfull to other users. And I can accept your answer